# How to access allocated memory in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

After using malloc() to initialize 5000 bytes of memory, how would I reference the bytes in this memory space? For example, if I need to point to a starting location of data within the memory, how would I go about that?

EDIT: Does it matter what I use to point to it? I mean I am seeing people use bytes/int/char? Is it relevant?

Error I get:
[image]

Comment: The problem in your screenshot is that you are using `sizeOf` instead of `sizeof`. Also, `mem` appears to be a macro, which is expanding into something unexpected and causing problems.

Comment: What do you mean it is a macro? I have it in the header as #define mem...that's probably an incorrect way to declare it? How would I write a declaration for mem?

Comment: `#define mem` defines `mem` to be a [macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) that expands to nothing. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. If mem was not already `#defined` as a macro you would be declaring it with the syntax `byte *mem`. This would be very problematic, because it would mean that calling `MemoryManager` would do nothing except leak memory.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I don't need to define it in the header!

Comment: You might find these useful, [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subscript `array[n]` operator to access the index you are interested in reading/writing, like so:

```
uint8_t* const bytes = (uint8_t*)malloc(5000);

bytes[0] = UINT8_MAX; // << write UINT8_MAX to the first element
uint8_t valueAtIndexZero = bytes[0]; // << read the first element (will be UINT8_MAX)
...
free(bytes), bytes = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char * buffer = malloc(5000);

buffer[idx] = whatever;

char * p = buffer + idx;
*p = whatever;
```

Answer (score 0):

Malloc doesn't initialize the bits allocated by it. Use [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/) rather.

```
int *p = malloc (5000); // p points to the start of the dynamically allocated area.
```

Comment: So, if the pointer points to 100 (as the start of the allocated area), and my data is stored at 150, how would I reference that spot? Would I just literally say p + 50?

Comment: @antonpug : Correct!! To use the value at that location you could write p[50].

Comment: Can I do the same with bytes? like @TTimo mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` returns a pointer to the allocated memory:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
byte * mem = malloc( 5000 );

byte val = mem[1000]; /* gets the 1000th byte */
```

Comment: initialize(int bytes)
{
    typedef unsigned char byte; byte *mem = malloc(bytes);
} <BR> I get an error on *mem says Expected Identifier

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by others, you could do something like this:

```
int nbytes = 23; // number of bytes of space to allocate
byte *stuff = malloc(nbytes * sizeof stuff[0]);

stuff[0] = 0; // set the first byte to 0
byte x = stuff[0]; // get the first byte

int n = 3;
stuff[n] = 0; // set the nth byte to 0
x = stuff[n]; // nth byte, or in the case of some other type, nth whatever - just make sure it's a safe value, from 0 (inclusive) to the number (nbytes here) of things you allocated (exclusive)
```

However, a couple of things to note:

1. `malloc` will not initialise the memory, but `calloc` will (as mentioned by Prasoon Saurav)
2. You should always check to see if the memory allocation failed (see below for an example)

```
int nbytes = 23; // or however many you want  
byte *stuff = malloc(nbytes * sizeof stuff[0]);

if (NULL == stuff) // memory allocation failed!
{
 //handle it here, e.g. by exiting the program and displaying an appropriate error message
}

stuff[0] = 0; // set the first byte to 0
byte x = stuff[0]; // get the first byte

int n = 3;
stuff[n] = 0; // set the nth byte to 0
x = stuff[n]; // nth byte, or in the case of some other type, nth whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

> After using malloc() to initialize 5000 bytes of memory, how would I
>   reference the bytes in this memory space? For example, if I need to
>   point to a starting location of data within the memory, how would I go
>   about that?
>
> Does it matter what I use to point to it? I mean I am seeing people
>   use bytes/int/char? Is it relevant?

as you have seen malloc allocates a block of memory counted in bytes, you can assign a pointer to that block and *depending on the pointer type* the compiler knows how to reference individual elements:

```
unsigned char *memblob = malloc( 1024 );
short* pshort = (short*)memblob;
```

now if you reference the second short value i.e. `*(pshort + 1)` or `pshort[1]` the compiler knows that it needs to add 2 bytes (`sizeof(short)`) in order get the next element.

```
float* pfloat = (float*)memblob;
```

now if you reference the second float value i.e. `*(pfloat + 1)` or `pfloat[1]` the compiler knows that it needs to add 4 bytes (`sizeof(float)`) in order get the next element.

same with own defined data types:

```
typedef struct s
{
  short a;
  long  b;
} mystruct_t;

mystruct_t* pstruct = (mystruct_t*)memblob;
```

`pstruct + 1` accesses the `struct` at offset `sizeof(mystruct_t)`

so it is really up to you how you want to use the allocated memory